# Send data from android to website but no result returned

Tags: java, android

I am totally new in java and android.. I am sure I did it wrong on the code, please help me fix it

I try to send the content of a tweet as a String from an android application to this online parser: http://demo.ark.cs.cmu.edu/parse, and I want to retrieve the result of the parsing, here is my code:

```
@Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        String Tobetag = urlEncode(contentTweet);
        new Analyser().execute();
        }


    private String urlEncode(String s){
                      try {
                        return URLEncoder.encode(s,"UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
                      }
                     catch (  UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(s,e);
                      }
                    }

        private class Analyser extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer>
                {
                    private String mUrl = "http://demo.ark.cs.cmu.edu/parse?sentence=";

                @Override
                protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    try 
                    {
                        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                        request.setURI(new URI(mUrl + mTobetag));
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(in) );
                        String result = reader.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Top");
                        System.out.println(result);
                        System.out.println("Bottom");

                        in.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.e("Twitter", "doInBackground_" + e.toString());
                        }
                    return new Integer(1);
                }


                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                    }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Integer i) {

                    }

                }
```

I ran the code, no error reported but I didn't get the parse result, I only have this:

[image]

What can I do to get the result I wanted?

P.S. Also I am not sure I used the urlencoder right, it turn the slashes of the tweet content into %2F, but when I use the online parser by a browser, it shows that it doesn't change the slashed at all, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading only the first line of the response, if you want to read the entire response you can do it like this:

```
String result = "";
for(String line;(line=br.readLine())!=null;){
        result += line;
}
```

This will get you the entire `http://demo.ark.cs.cmu.edu/parse` page as a response, if you want the response to be only a JSON object, use this URL instead `http://demo.ark.cs.cmu.edu/parse/api/v1/parse?sentence=....`

Comment: Thanks ! Although I changed the URL to the one you mentioned, the output became a symbol { and there is only this .. why?

Comment: `{` is the first line in the response, are you sure you are reading the entire response using the method that I've provided ?

Comment: ah yes I understood it wrong I thought it's changing either the URL or the method, thanks ! ;)